# Javascript Angular / Firebase auto keys has "-" remove or add own

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on an angular 2 / firebase project.

I have this function which adds a new record to firebase:

```
addItem(newTitle: string, newText: string) {
    this.items.push({ title: newTitle, text: newText });
  }
```

This will add something like this to the firebase database:

1st it creates a unique id/key:

```
-KkztvsKvtqCfoFlpdFc

  title: mytitle

  text: mytext here
```

I have a problem with the key it add. It starts with a -

So I either need a way to generate my own unique id/key or get firebase to not add the -

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algorithm for generating push ids is described here: firebase.googleblog.com/2015/02/the-2120-ways-to-ensure-unique_68.html. The code is shown in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/mikelehen/3596a30bd69384624c11).

You can easily take the `-` our of the dictionary (`PUSH_CHARS`) and generate keys without them.

Comment: I'm not too sure if I want to change the lib code as it will stop working when the library is updated. Is there a way to generate my own?

Comment: 1) Make a copy of the code 2) Modify it to your needs (i.e. remove the `-`) 3) now it's your own.

Comment: Strange, I cannot find that file in angularfire2 which is what I'm using

Comment: What file? The gist I linked provides the code of a function that you can copy and modify to your needs.